# Vue 3 Render Functions - Append child element to VNode on click event

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, vue-render-function

I’m trying to dynamically append a VNode to a container on a click event from the user.

I was expecting the code below to append a new child to the container div each time the button is clicked but what’s happening is that upon each click the previous child is replaced by the new one inside the div as the following [gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yNlsa.gif) illustrates.

How could I following the same concept, of dynamically creating VNodes, achieve the outcome of appending a node without replacing the previous one?

```js
import {defineComponent, h, createVNode, render} from "vue";

export default defineComponent({
    setup() {
        return () => {
          const container = h('div', []);
          const button = h('button', {
            onClick: () => {
              const node = createVNode('div', null,[`Time: ${new Date().toISOString()}`]);
              node.appContext = container.appContext;
              render(node, container.el as any);
            }
          }, ['Add New'])
          container.children?.push(button);
          return container;
        };
    }
})
```

(For reference I’ve followed this [tutorial](https://javascript.tutorialink.com/vue-3-append-component-to-the-dom-best-practice/))

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 0):

With `render(node, container.el as any);` you replace the inner HTML of your `div` container every time with the new created node. This approach is questioned. Since:

> This approach relies on internal methods (`createVNode` and `render`), which could
> be refactored or removed in a future release.

I would just use Vue reactivity instead of rendering new `vnodes`.

```js
const { createApp, defineComponent, h, createVNode, render, ref } = Vue;

const MyComponent = {
 setup() {
        const children = ref([]);        
        return () => {
          const button = h('button', {
            onClick: () => {
              children.value.push(`Time: ${new Date().toISOString()}`);
            }
          }, ['Add New']);
          const list = h('ul', 
            children.value.map((text) => {
               return h('li', null, text)
            })
          );
          return h('div', [button, list]);
        };
    }
}

const App = {}
const app = createApp(App)
app.component('MyComponent', MyComponent)
app.mount('#app')
```

```html
<div id="app"> 
  <my-component />
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
```

Or even do it much simpler, like this

```js
const { createApp, ref } = Vue;

const MyComponent = {
 setup() {
    const items = ref([]);
    const addNew = () => items.value.push(`Time: ${new Date().toISOString()}`);
    return {items, addNew}
 },
  template: `
  <div>
      <button @click="addNew()">Add New</button>
      <ul><li v-for="text in items">{{ text }}</li></ul>
  </div>`
  }

const App = {
  components: {MyComponent}
}
const app = createApp(App)
app.mount('#app')
```

```html
<div id="app"> 
  <my-component />
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
```